# Using a bash script to set up Proxies on macOS

Tags: terminal, network, mojave, proxy

**Mojave 10.14.6**

My company use Proxy. One Proxy for HTTP and One Proxy for HTTPS and some Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains.

I was not able to reach google.com website because I had to specify the proxy which I did and everything is working as expected.

But I want to automate my process instead of using the GUI.

I have a strange behavior with my script below when I try to set up: System Preferences > Network > "Example Wi-Fi" > Advanced > Proxies.

Again, if I set all the Proxies parameters using the GUI (manually) everything is working as expected **but I if try to use my script below I am having issues like I cannot reach web sites, etc.**

I am pretty sure I am missing some command lines from my script.  The funny things that when I run the script I can literally see all the parameters being applied to the GUI (Network > Proxies), as if I had to manually inserted. Again they are all there.  I tried to reboot my Mac Laptop, I also try to reset some DNS cache but nothing, still same strange issue.

What could be the issue? What command line from the script I am missing?

See my script below (for security reasons I am faking the IP address and domain name.)

Thank you in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-Fi" 10.10.10.10 8080
networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi" 10.10.10.20 8443 
networksetup -setproxybypassdomains "Wi-Fi" "127.0.0.1,*.local,169.254/16,*.subdomain.maindomain.com,*.maindomain.com"
networksetup -setwebproxystate "Wi-Fi" on
```

Comment: Thanks to take the time to answer me.  Well the location must be only one.  The user must use those system global proxy configurations regardless if they are WiFi or Connected to Work Lan and regardless if they are home or at work.  I am the one setting up these macOS laptop, I use Jamf as MDM but I am trying to not to manually typed everything all these proxy settings but create a script and push it.  The problem is with my script.  thanks a lot.

Comment: I am interested  in your problem and the problem you found in your shell script: I want to master everything which might be hidden under GUI.